# How do I remove a comma off the end of a string?

Tags: php

I want to remove the comma off the end of a string. As it is now I am using

```
$string = substr($string,0,-1);
```

but that only removes the last character of the string. I am adding the string dynamically, so sometimes there is no comma at the end of the string. How can I have PHP remove the comma off the end of the string if there is one at the end of it?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

```
$string = rtrim($string, ',');
```

[Docs for `rtrim` here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Comment: This will remove multiple commas: "a,b,,," will become "a,b". Whether that's what the OP wants or not I don't know...

Comment: Thank you, I was doing this with substr, strlen,... all my life

Answer (score 48):

This is a classic question, with two solutions. If you want to remove exactly one comma, which may or may not be there, use:

```
if (substr($string, -1, 1) == ',')
{
  $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
}
```

If you want to remove all commas from the end of a line use the simpler:

```
$string = rtrim($string, ',');
```

The rtrim function (and corresponding ltrim for left trim) is very useful as you can specify a range of characters to remove, i.e. to remove commas and trailing whitespace you would write:

```
$string = rtrim($string, ", \t\n");
```

Answer (score 15):

i guess you're concatenating something in the loop, like

```
foreach($a as $b)
  $string .= $b . ',';
```

much better is to collect items in an array and then join it with a delimiter you need

```
foreach($a as $b)
  $result[] = $b;

$result = implode(',', $result);
```

this solves trailing and double delimiter problems that usually occur with concatenation

Comment: Good suggestion.  However, not all concatenations may take place in PHP.  In my case, I am sending a Javascript concatenated string for PHP to unravel.

Comment: This is beautiful and now I have to rewrite everything. Can't believe I overlooked such a simple and straightforward answer

Comment: @Sablefoste ...then don't send a mess to unravel.  Javascript has `join()` as well.

Answer (score 9):

If you're concatenating something in the loop, you can do it in this way too:

```
$coma = "";
foreach($a as $b){
    $string .= $coma.$b;
    $coma = ",";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

have a look at the rtrim function

```
rtrim ($string , ",");
```

the above line will remove a char if the last char is a comma

Answer (score 1):

```
if(substr($str, -1, 1) == ',') {

  $str = substr($str, 0, -1);

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

A simple regular expression would work

```
$string = preg_replace("/,$/", "", $string)
```

Comment: Developer use regular expression to solve a problem and now he has two problems.

Answer (score 1):

rtrim ($string , ","); is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a pesky "invisible" space at the end of my string and had to do this

```
 $update_sql=rtrim(trim($update_sql),',');
```

But a solution above is better

```
 $update_sql=rtrim($update_sql,', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Precede that with:

```
if(substr($string, -1)==",")
```