# how to not explode comma in the middle of an array in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array in javascript that separated with `,`. but inside of them there are some values containing `,` as it's value. my problem is I don't want to explode such these values but the php does it. Is there any way to handle it?

```
<form id="form" method="post">
<table>
<tr val="sprots, music, videos"><td>sprots, music, videos</td></tr>
......
......
<tr val="car"><td>car</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="category" id="category" value="">
</form>
<script>
    var Data=[];
    $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
       Data.push($(this).attr('val'));
    });
$('#category').val(Data);
</script>

<?php
$category=$_POST['category'];
$tmp=explode(',',$category);
?>
```

the problem occurs when it wants to explode value like this:`array[0]='sports, music,videos'`. it explodes it as 3 separated array which is sth like this:
array[0]='sports', array[1]='music', array[2]='videos'.
I want to explode this value as a unique part, I mean like this:
`array[0]='sports, music,videos'`

Comment: show `var_dump($category); ` from your code

Comment: You may need the implode not the explode..

Comment: Then do not `explode`. Or first remove from string items you don't won't to be exploded.

Comment: Show input and output data You want.

Comment: how you generate that comma separated string ? if you generate from your side then you can use any other separator for separate value

Comment: @DineshBhojvani. javascript add `,` between it's array .

Answer (score 1):

as Dinesh Suggested you can change separator, instead of comma use something that never get you in trouble

for Example:

```
var Data=[];
$('table').find('tr').each(function(){
   Data.push('~'+ $(this).attr('val'));
});
console.log(Data);
```

**Output :**

```
["~sprots, music, videos", "~car"]
```

But when you Post data it will become like `~sprots, music, videos,~car` 
in server side You have to do something like this

```
<?php
$category=$_POST['category'];
$tmp=explode('~',$category);
unset($tmp[0]);
var_dump($tmp);
?>
```

**Output :**

```
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  string(22) "sprots, music, videos,"
  [2] =>
  string(3) "car"
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't add `~` at the first value. what's wrong with it?

Comment: If the output would be as you mentioned, there is no problem but the output is like this:`[~sports, music, videos,~car]`. it adds additional `,` because the `,` after videos, will be put inside array[0].

Comment: I am not clear. can you please add your input and output

Comment: in client-side it shows the correct form, sth like this:
`array[0]="sports, music, videos"/ array[1]="car",...` but when I get at server-side, I get the array like this:`[~sports,music,videos,~car]`.if I can get this array at server-side like this , the problem will be solved.`array[0]='sprort, music,videos', array[1]="car",...

Comment: yes, this given code will add `[~sports,music,videos,~car]` in your hidden form attribute "category".  so, i think as per current situation your problem is solved.

Comment: yes but another problem is appeared and that's additional `,`. in this situation at the end of each explode, add`,`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642698/how-do-i-remove-a-comma-off-the-end-of-a-string