# Add commas in between <a>-elements in a string with php

Tags: php, string, foreach

Is it possible with php to make a string of, say, `<a>`-elements comma-separated?

The situation is that a `foreach` loop appends a number of `<a>` links to an `$output` variable one after the other:

```
$output = '<a>link</a><a>link</a><a>link</a><a>link</a><a>link</a>';
```

Is it afterwards possible in php to comma-separate them and achieve the below string?

```
$output = '<a>link</a>,<a>link</a>,<a>link</a>,<a>link</a>,<a>link</a>';
```

Or is the most efficient way to add the comma inside the `foreach` loop (and then to use an `if`-command to skip the last one, or something like that, since that will add one comma too many)?

Comment: Check out the [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function

Comment: @dazed-and-confused Thanks for the suggestion. With `implode` I will have to store my `<a>` links in an array instead of appending them onto the same string. Would this be a smarter or a slower method?

Comment: I'm not too sure about speed, I go by whatever is easier to work with. I think keeping the strings in an array and then using `implode()` will be your best bet. No `if` this is the last one, don't include the `,` No remove trailing `,` after the loop. It's just cleaner

Comment: With a string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642698/how-do-i-remove-a-comma-off-the-end-of-a-string

Comment: now you have multiple and duplicate options, try them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that the array implode method is probably most common way to concatenate multiple elements like this, which has already been posted in another answer.

Depending on your situation, this might however not always be the case, so for the sake of completion I'd like to add that you can also use the `rtrim` function to easily remove any trailing commas when concatenating strings:

```
foreach($links as $link) {
   $output .= '<a>link</a>,';
}
$output = rtrim($output, ',');
```

Documentation for rtrim can be read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$output = preg_replace("/a><a","/a>,<a",$output);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple replace might do the job for you:

```
preg_replace('/a><a/','a>,<a',$s);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `foreach` loop, rather than concatenating the item on to the end of an existing string, push them to an array:

```
$parts = array();

foreach($list as $item){
    $parts[] = "<a>$item</a>";
}
```

Then, you can simply join ([*implode*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)) the array elements together to get your desired result:

```
$output = implode(',', $parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 solutions

**solution 1 (with [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)):**

```
$output = '<a>link</a><a>link</a><a>link</a><a>link</a><a>link</a>';
echo str_replace("</a>","</a>,", $output);
```

**Solution 2 (with [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) method):**

```
$exploded = explode("</a>",$output);
echo implode("</a>,", $exploded);
```

**Side Note:** you can remove the last `"," by using [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) method

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `</a>` with `</a>,`, then `trim` the last `,', check [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6ea9ada31345cc76a7847af9656e39415fe20413)

```
echo rtrim(str_replace("</a>","</a>,",$output),",");
```