# How to remove characters at the end of a string in PHP using rtrim function properly

Tags: php, gravityforms

I have a gravity form that takes input from a user and then creates a notification email from the input.

On the backend, I have the notification setup to build out an html email. It generates an H2 tag from selections from a checkbox.

The H2 ends up looking like this: VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, !

I would like to remove the comma and the exclamation point at the end of this H2.

Here is my code:

```
 function alter_ad( $notification, $form, $entry ) {
     //grab the message portion of the notification
     $data = $notification['message'];
     //find the h2 header in the notification
     preg_match('/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/s', $data, $match);
     //store the content h2 in variable
     $header = $match[1];
     //trim off the exclamation point
     $new_header = rtrim($header, '!');
     //now trim off the comma at the end
     $new_header_two = rtrim($new_header, ',');
     //now header should have the comma and exclamation at the end removed
     //so now I need to find the h2 in the message again and replace its contents with the new 
     header text
     $start = '<h2>';
     $end =  '</h2>';

     $result = replace_content_inside_delimiters($start, $end, $new_header_two, $data);

     $notification['message'] = $result;

     return $notification;

   }

   function replace_content_inside_delimiters($start, $end, $new, $source) {
     return preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($start).')(.*?)('.preg_quote($end).')#si', 
    '$1'.$new.'$3', $source);
   }

  add_filter( 'gform_notification_42', 'alter_ad', 10, 3 );
```

However, when I submit the notification, it removes the exclamation point, but the trailing comma is still there. Am I doing something wrong with the second rtrim()?

The h2 header in the notification ends up looking like this after running through the filter:

VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642800/2943403

Answer (score 2):

Well, the string you provided in this case has exclamation mark `!` then space   and then comma `,`.

So

```
 //trim off the exclamation point
 $header= rtrim($header, "!");

 //now trim off the space
 $header= rtrim($header, " ");

 //now trim off the comma at the end
 $header= rtrim($header, ",");
```

or in a single line:

```
$header = rtrim($header, "! ,");
```

See the code example here: http://codepad.org/PNqjFL8h

Answer (score 0):

The most important skill in debugging is **breaking the problem down**.

Most of the code you've shown us is not relevant to the problem, and the actual [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is this:

```
$header = 'VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, !';
//trim off the exclamation point
$new_header = rtrim($header, '!');
//now trim off the comma at the end
$new_header_two = rtrim($new_header, ',');

echo $new_header_two;
```

Next, look carefully at what is in `$new_header`, using a function like [var_dump](https://php.net/var_dump):

```
string(87) "VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, "
```

Notice that the last character is *not* a comma, it is a space. So you need to remove that as well:

```
$header = 'VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, !';
//trim off the exclamation point
$new_header = rtrim($header, '!');
// Next there's a space
$new_header_two = rtrim($new_header, ' ');
//now trim off the comma at the end
$new_header_three = rtrim($new_header_two, ',');

echo $new_header_three;
```

Since [rtrim](https://www.php.net/rtrim) can strip multiple characters at once, you can simplify this to one line:

```
$header = 'VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, !';
// trim off any number of trailing commas, spaces, and exclamation marks
$new_header = rtrim($header, '!, ');

echo $new_header;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = "VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, !";
$new_string = rtrim($string, ", !");
echo $new_string;
// Outputs: VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[`rtrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) can take a list of character and metacharacters. The advantage of this is you can build a list of items to be removed from the end of the string instead of doing individual removals.

```
// Sample string
$str = 'VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, !';

// Full list for unwanted characters
$rmv = ",! \n\r\t\v\0";

// test it
var_dump(rtrim($str,$rmv));
```

Which will output:

```
string(85) "VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like (not using rtrim) :

```
$str = 'VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job, !';

$string = implode(',', array_slice(explode(',', $str), 0, -1 ));
//Output => VETERINARY ASSISTANT WANTED: Progressive Practice, The Best Clients, Learn On the Job
```